# how to create admin-bro image field

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, admin-bro

Im using admin-bro 3.3.1

I try to change one of my field to "dropZone" to drop images inside this field, i follow the tutorial but the field still regular text field . why?

```
const options = {
options: {
    listProperties: ["fileUrl", "mimeType"],
},
features: [
    uploadFeature({
        provider: {
            aws: {
                accessKeyId: process.env.AKN7H,
                secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                region: "EUdon) eust-2",
                bucket: "ba",
            },
        },
        properties: {
            key: "fileUrl", // to this db field feature will safe S3 key,
            mimeType: "mimeType", // this property is important because allows to have previews,
        },
        validation: {
            mimeTypes: "application/pdf",
        },
    }),
],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 validation: {
        mimeTypes: "application/pdf",
    },
```

'mimeTypes'  + for array : mimeTypes: ["application/pdf"]

'mimeType'  + for string : mimeTypes: "application/pdf"